# Xcode 4: deleting items in Build Settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

In XCode 4.0 there's a newly designed Build Settings page. My problem is that I can't see how to remove a setting once I've specified it.

Example: I've changed "Versioning System" to "Apple Generic" at the target level. Afterwards I realised I should set it at the project level, and so I want to delete the target level setting. However, there's no way I can see to remove the setting -- you click on it and there's two options, neither of which is the default "not specified" empty setting. Hitting the delete key on the keyboard nothing.

The same goes for fields that accept text -- if I try to delete a setting by just deleting all the text set, it still shows that field in green, but with no text in it, and regards it as the presence of a setting.

Comment: NOTE: This doesn't seem to work any more in Xcode 4.3. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170410/how-to-delete-user-defined-build-settings-in-xcode-4-3-1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Delete works but you have to take care to have the proper item selected on the left hand side of the editor area.

If you want to default a target setting to the project or "Mac Os Default" value, you first need to select the target on the left hand side of the editor area, go to build settings and you will be able to remove the target setting using the delete key. You will not be able to remove project settings from here though.

If you want to default a project setting to the "Mac Os Default" value, you first need to select the project on the left hand side of the editor area, go to build settings and only then you will be able to erase the setting of the project using the delete key.

I'm not sure if that is a bug of XCode or not. The truth is that when you are looking to the settings of a target and you hit delete, Xcode has no way to know if you want to delete a project or a target setting, because there is not way to select a column, but only rows... and it seems logical that it deletes only a target one. So it is probably the normal behavior.

Comment: Thanks, will try again on Monday, it sounds like the Delete key should just work -- it would make sense! -- so am confused as to why mine wouldn't.

Comment: I though mine was not working either until I find out about the project/target selection in the left hand side of the editor. ;-)

Comment: Also, you can only delete individual settings using the 'Delete' key not complete sections of rows. You can't delete the 'Code Signing Identity' section only the individual rows of that section.

Answer (score 6):

Highlighting the setting's row and hitting the delete key works for me. That is, in any non-user-defined settings, hitting delete removes all customization of the settings; in user-defined settings, it deletes the setting entirely.