# How to delete user-defined build settings in Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: xcode, build-settings

I have created several user-defined build settings in Xcode 4.3.1. I no longer need these settings and want to delete them, but there doesn't seem to be a way to delete them!

I am aware that these are stored in the project settings (project.pbxproj) file located within the xcodeproj file. But I don't want to edit these in a text editor as there are all sorts of repetitions and guids which I don't understand.

Any suggestions on how I can do this within Xcode? (or have they forgotten to add a "delete" button)

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350438/xcode-4-deleting-items-in-build-settings

Comment: I don't think so. That answer doesn't work for user-defined build settings.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just figured this out myself: you need to make sure you're at the right scope to be able to delete the setting. If you defined the setting at the project scope, no amount of key-bashing will remove it if you're looking at the target-scope. Remember, targets inherit settings from project scope. That last bit is what I tripped over :)

Comment: You can tell if it's the right scope by examining the setting. If it's bold then you're in the right place and can go ahead and delete. Otherwise, if the setting font appears normal, then the setting has been set elsewhere and inherited.

Comment: Selecting `Levels` rather than `Combined` really helps for finding where a setting is coming from.

Comment: Once you find the right scope (selecting Levels as indicated by funroll) pressing 'delete' won't work. Instead, double-click the identifier to open the editor and then use the delete key

Answer (score 49):

Try selecting a user-defined setting that you created then hit "Delete" button on your keyboard. That works for me when I encountered the same problem.

Comment: No, you have to be at the right scope to delete the setting. [Brian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10628150/80425) is correct.

Comment: Well, _I_ found this valuable... since right-click had no "DELETE" and there was no minus-sign-shaped button near the plus-sign. :)

Answer (score 19):

**On Xcode 6**: 

Select the row and hit <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, this works but it really has to be on the project level. On target level it won't work if it inherits from the project, i.e., it won't disappear even after you hit the Fn + Delete. Good thing is that the UI will imply that it's an inherited field (the filed name would be in bold if it were the source).

Answer (score 8):

Follow the steps below:

1. Select Project
2. Tap on the `Info` tab
3. Select `Configurations`
4. Select Configuration to remove
5. Press the `Delete` button on the keyboard

Comment: Deleting User-defined build configuration can be done in the same steps on Xcode 12.3 too.

Answer (score 4):

Removing **User-Defined build settings** depends on where those settings have been created.

Lets assume that you've created one already and named it as **PROJECT_SETTING**. In order to check your PROJECT related **User-Defined settings**, you have to select your project first on the **project and targets list**, then you should see something like this:

[image]

> Here you can **see only PROJECT** related settings, and here you have the
>   only ability **edit/delete PROJECT_SETTING**.

Besides that if you set up a **TARGET**, so can add new **User-Defined settings** there, that only affects that **TARGET** scope.

[image]

> You can **edit/delete TARGET_SETTING_1** and **TARGET_SETTING_2** here, but
>   **PROJECT_SETTING** is **read-only**, as it is inherited from your
>   PROJECT settings.

Here you will notice that your TARGET contains your PROJECT **User-Defined settings** and also your TARGET related **User-Defined settings** marked as **bold letters**. This helps you to know which setting can be edited on this level.

You won't be able to delete your settings here if that was created under PROJECT scope, and also editing a PROJECT related **User-Defined settings** will result a newly created settings that affects only the selected TARGET.

Also if you prefer more visibility on **Build Settings**, you can select **Levels** view instead of **Combined** view, so you should see it more separated:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select one of them and press keyboard's delete button.

Answer (score 0):

There's a caveat to these answers: If you're using a [Build Configuration File (.xcconfig)](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.3/#/deve97bde215) it doesn't seem possible to delete the user-defined settings generated from these files directly on either the project or target level in the "Build Settings" GUI.  You'll have to delete the flag and its value from the configuration file and rebuild the project.  If you're using multiple build configuration files that use the same flag, you'll have to delete them from each file.

Although settings that come from these configuration files are displayed in the `User Defined` build settings section (just like any other user-defined flag that one would create from the GUI), they are not written to the `.xcodeproj` file like the settings that one adds from the GUI are (which probably prevents them from being able to be deleted from the GUI).  They are also not displayed in bold text like these GUI-added settings are.